# Can't see japanese keyboard in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype, cjk

I have added japanese keyboard from settings of iphone. However I am not able to see it or change it in the app by pressing globe icon.

Is there is way to add japanese keyboard for my app so that I can write japanese text. I have googled it. However didn't get any lead for adding japanese keyboard in the app, I am getting all the results related to localization and internationalisation.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings App -> General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> Add New, then Select language keyboard, in your case select Japanese and then select language from Kana or Romaji and press Done.

After this you can see all selected keyboard list in Keyboards section.
This will add Japanese Keyboard in all Applications, you don't have to do any special in your Application.

You can also test this on simulator.

Edit Scheme -> Run -> Options -> Application Language, and select your language.

Comment: I have already done with the things you have mentioned but it didn't help. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: did you checked it with simulator?

Comment: Yes i did check with simulator as well it did not work.